# dynamically background image don't work on android with ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi I want load dynamically background on `Android` with ionic 3

I try this

```
[style.backgroundImage]="'url(assets/imgs/' + station.name + '.jpg)'"
```

And

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(../../assets/imgs/' + station.name + '.jpg)'}"
```

Work on `iOS` and `Browser` but not working on `Android`

Can you help me ?

Comment: Try this one from my working code - [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+Dynamic image path+')'"

Answer (score 0):

I did like the following and successful:

**.html**

```
<ion-content no-padding [style.background]="'url(assets/imgs/' + station.name + '.png)'"> 

</ion-content>
```

**.ts**

```
export class Page1Page {
  station: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.station = {
      name: "logo",
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the image file should be placed in the correct folder:

[image]

I used `logo.png` in my machine, but you could use another image.

Answer (score 0):

```js
styleData = {
    "someCSSproperty": "someValue",
    "background-image":`url('assets/imgs/'${station.name}'.jpg)`
}
```

normally such url requires quotation marks, hence Android may not like it without those:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

- **You have:** url(assets/imgs/image.jpg)
- **You should have:** url("assets/imgs/image.jpg")

Now since you want to use ngStyle binding I would recommend:

1. In your ts file have object that defines the style and use **back quotes** there (sorry paasting a pitcure here as pre-code here doesn't like back quote:
   [image]
2. Bind in your template:

   [ngStyle]="styleData"

Let me know if this helps.